# ReactJS SubmissionError Uncaught Error in Promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, form-submit, redux-form

Hey guys I have been trying to figure out this issue I am having for a while now to no avail. I have a form that validates a email and password through firebase to let a person login, and when this validation fails I want to throw an error back to my form that will then display inline to let the user know the login failed. My issue is whenever I hit an error I am throw the error:

[image]

My code is as follows:

**LoginForm.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { reduxForm, Field } from "redux-form";
import { Form, Button, Grid, Label } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { login } from "../authActions";
import TextInput from "../../../app/common/form/TextInput";

const actions = {
  login
};

class LoginForm extends Component {
  initiateLogin = values => {
    this.props.login(values, this.props.history);
  };

  onFormSubmit = values => {
    this.initiateLogin(values);
  };

  render() {
    const { error } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Column width={16}>
          <Form
            size="large"
            onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit)}
          >
            <Field
              name="email"
              type="text"
              component={TextInput}
              placeholder="email"
            />
            <Field
              name="password"
              type="text"
              component={TextInput}
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            {error && (
              <Label basic color="red">
                {error}
              </Label>
            )}
            <Button className="loginBtn">Login</Button>
          </Form>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    null,
    actions
  )(reduxForm({ form: "loginForm" })(LoginForm))
);
```

**authActions.jsx**

```js
import { SubmissionError } from "redux-form";
import { SIGN_OUT_USER } from "./authConstants";
import { closeModal } from "../modals/modalActions";

export const login = (creds, history) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    try {
      console.log("zero");
      await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(creds.email, creds.password);
      console.log("first");
      dispatch(closeModal());
      console.log("second");
      history.push("/profile");
      console.log("third");
    } catch (error) {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        _error: "Login Failed"
      });
    }
  };
};

export const logout = () => {
  return {
    type: SIGN_OUT_USER
  };
};
```

So on submission of my form I call handleSubmit and pass my own custom method which then goes on to call one of my authAction methods. This method throws a SubmissionError if the sign in does not work and in theory I want this error to then be updated in my LoginForm in my error prop so that I can then update the dom with an error message inline.

The problem is I am not able to do "throw new SubmissionError" from within my login authAction. I assume that this has something to do with an non returned promise (and / or) how I am using my handleSubmit method. I have looked around for a while but can't get anything to work.

Thanks guys.

Comment: `this.initiateLogin(values).catch(err => do something with the error here perhaps)`

Comment: I am getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Comment: oh, yeah, ... because you'd need `return this.props.login(values, this.props.history);`

Comment: ah ok so I would add the catch in my first method and return the promise from my initiateLogin method that makes perfect sense. I won't be able to try this for a day but I will get back to you thursday

Comment: Sweet so I am able to return the error in the catch but how can I update my dom now like I wanted to ? So now an error shows up with the label? Also I still get the first two errors

Comment: I solved it by just adding some state with error to my component, posted above

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I added a catch to my onFormSubmit method (while also deleting the other needless method) and then using this caught error to then update the state of my component (I added a new state). See below:

```js
 state = {
    error: null
  }

  onFormSubmit = values => {
    this.props
      .login(values, this.props.history)
      .catch(err => this.setState({error: err.errors._error})) 
  };
```

So my main problem was I needed to catch this error I was throwing inside my authActions.jsx file. And in theory my stuff should be workign with SubmissionError to update the error prop but it was not so I worked around that by just adding some state with an error field that I just update once I catch an error.